# Python: rearranging data collection

Tags: python, array, collections

Let's say I have a data collection, like a list, containing a set of objects with particular properties. Let's go with animals:

```
[ cow, sheep, orangutan ]
```

An animal has a property `animal_data` that contains taxonomic information, like `kingdom`,  `class`, `family` and `species`. This establishes a hierarchy which says that each property is contained in the previous one, sort of like a linear many-to-one tree.

Now we want to rearrange the former collection into a data structure that groups each animal into their own species, family, class and kingdom. We'd end up with something like this:

```
{
  "kingdoms": [
    {
      "name": "Animalia",
      "classes": [
        {
          "name": "Mammalia",
          "families": [
            {
              "name": "Bovidae",
              "species": [
                {
                  "name": "Bos taurus"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Bovis aries"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Hominidae",
              "species": [
                {
                  "name": "Pongo pygmaeus"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This would be our final data structure. And this is strictly how it should look like, I can't rearrange it to make it look better. I know that could be done, but that's just how it has to look like.

Now, being relatively new to Python, or at least to its functional potential, I tried using list comprehensions, `map`, `groupby` and lambdas to achieve that result. However, I couldn't get past the first level of nesting, because each group is dependant on the one on the higher level.

So this is my solution instead:

```
# group by kingdom
animals_dict = {kingdom: list(animals_by_kingdom) for kingdom, animals_by_kingdom in
                groupby(animals, lambda a: a.animal_data.kingdom)}

grouped_animals = defaultdict(list)
for kingdom, animals_by_kingdom in animals_dict.items():
    # group by class
    classes_dict = {animal_class: list(animals_by_class) for animal_class, animals_by_class in
                    groupby(animals_by_kingdom, lambda a: a.animal_data.animal_class)}

    classes = []
    for animal_class, animals_by_class in classes_dict.items():
        # group by family
        families_dict = {family: list(animals_by_family) for family, animals_by_family in
                         groupby(animals_by_class, lambda a: a.animal_data.family)}

        families = []
        for family, animals_by_family in families_dict.items():
            families.append(
                {"name": family, "species": [{"name": animal.animal_data.species} for animal in animals_by_family]})

        classes.append({"name": animal_class, "families": families})

    grouped_animals["kingdoms"].append({"name": kingdom, "classes": classes})
```

This is the best I could do, but something tells me Python has a potential that'd allow me to do this more elegantly, compressed and clear.

I'd really appreaciate if any of you could give me tips in how to enhance my code and how to use Python tools to do it more properly and clearly (if it can indeed be done better).

---

Disclaimers:

- I cannot modify the initial data structure. If the `animal_data` property seems weird (instead of having the `kingdom`, `class`, etc. attached to the animal directly), that's just how it is.
- If you're wondering why would I rearrange the list in such a way, it is so it can be easily consumed by an endpoint that would work better with that format.

In case you need the `Animal` and `AnimalCode` to fiddle with this demo, here it is:

```
class AnimalData:
    def __init__(self, kingdom, animal_class, family, species):
        super().__init__()
        self.kingdom = kingdom
        self.animal_class = animal_class
        self.family = family
        self.species = species

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "Kingdom=%s, Class=%s, Family=%s, Species=%s" % (
            self.kingdom, self.animal_class, self.family, self.species)


class Animal:
    def __init__(self, kingdom, animal_class, family, species):
        super().__init__()
        self.animal_data = AnimalData(kingdom, animal_class, family, species)

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(self.animal_data)


cow = Animal("Animalia", "Mammalia", "Bovidae", "Bos taurus")
sheep = Animal("Animalia", "Mammalia", "Bovidae", "Bovis aries")
orangutan = Animal("Animalia", "Mammalia", "Hominidae", "Pongo pygmaeus")
animals = [cow, sheep, orangutan]
```

**Note**: The code works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

You should change `Animal` to be a child of `AnimalData`, or just not exist.
This allows you to remove all the `animal_data` boilerplate from say `animal.animal_data.kingdom`.

After this lets say that you can output the following data structure:

```
{
    "Animalia": {
        "Mammalia": {
            "Bovidae": [
                "Bos taurus"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I know you can't. But using that we could simplify all your code.
It'd simply become:

```
kingdoms = {}
kingdom = kingdoms.getdefault(animal.kingdom, {})
animal_class = kingdom.getdefault(animal.animal_class, {})
family = animal_class.getdefault(animal.family, [])
family.append(animal.species)
```

Or, a less ugly way:

```
kingdoms = {}
(kingdoms
    .getdefault(animal.kingdom, {})
    .getdefault(animal.animal_class, {})
    .getdefault(animal.family, [])
    .append(animal.species))
```

And so I'd either suggest that you change the data from the one that I've shown above to the one that you need.
Or make your own `getdefault`, that will allow you to do roughly the same.
In this you want to filter the list to get the first, and hopefully only, item with that key in the list.
If it doesn't exist, you want to make it your self, and for it to follow the structure you need.
To get a 'one to one' transform of `get_default` can lead to:

```
def get_default(list, key, value):
    v = next((i for i in list if i['name'] == key), None)
    if v is None:
        v = {
            'name': key,
            'value': value
        }
        list.append(v)
    return v['value']
```

However you don't really need to add the default `value`, so you can just set it to `[]`. And you need to change the `'value'` to something you can pass in.
Making these changes to the above can allow you to get:

```
def get_default(list, key, value):
    v = next((i for i in list if i['name'] == key), None)
    if v is None:
        v = {
            'name': key,
            value: []
        }
        list.append(v)
    return v[value]
```

And then you'd need to run this function.

```
kingdoms = []
kingdom = get_default(kingdoms, animal.kingdom, 'classes')
animal_class = get_default(kingdom, animal.animal_class, 'families')
family = get_default(animal_class, animal.family, 'species')
family.append({'name': animal.species})
```

*But* this isn't exactly what you want, and so we'd need to loop through each animal, and change the output to be correct.

```
def structure_animals(animals):
    kingdoms = []
    for animal in animals:
        kingdom = get_default(kingdoms, animal.kingdom, 'classes')
        animal_class = get_default(kingdom, animal.animal_class, 'families')
        family = get_default(animal_class, animal.family, 'species')
        family.append({'name': animal.species})
    return {'kingdoms': kingdoms}
```

---

The entire code changes I made:

```
import json

class AnimalData:
    def __init__(self, kingdom, animal_class, family, species):
        super().__init__()
        self.kingdom = kingdom
        self.animal_class = animal_class
        self.family = family
        self.species = species

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "Kingdom=%s, Class=%s, Family=%s, Species=%s" % (
            self.kingdom, self.animal_class, self.family, self.species)


class Animal(AnimalData):
    pass


def get_default(list, key, value):
    v = next((i for i in list if i['name'] == key), None)
    if v is None:
        v = {
            'name': key,
            value: []
        }
        list.append(v)
    return v[value]


def structure_animals(animals):
    kingdoms = []
    for animal in animals:
        kingdom = get_default(kingdoms, animal.kingdom, 'classes')
        animal_class = get_default(kingdom, animal.animal_class, 'families')
        family = get_default(animal_class, animal.family, 'species')
        family.append({'name': animal.species})
    return {'kingdoms': kingdoms}


cow = Animal("Animalia", "Mammalia", "Bovidae", "Bos taurus")
sheep = Animal("Animalia", "Mammalia", "Bovidae", "Bovis aries")
orangutan = Animal("Animalia", "Mammalia", "Hominidae", "Pongo pygmaeus")
animals = [cow, sheep, orangutan]

print(json.dumps(structure_animals(animals), sort_keys=True, indent=2))
```

Comment: As I said in my disclaimer I could NOT change the `Animal` or `AnimalData` classes and their relationships. Also the resulting data structure I showed as an example was strictly how I needed it. Placing the taxonomy element name in a `"name"` value instead of as the key was done in purpose, basically because there will be more properties, not just the name, and I'd want them on the same level instead of one as a key and the others as values. Also, going `"family": [ "species1, "species2" ]` doesn't work because of the same reasons. I'd need dicts, not plain strings.

Comment: @dabadaba Ok, ignore that _one_ point. Also you did read my answer right? It outputs the same as yours.

Comment: Yes of course I read it. I was just commenting on your first point. Just one slight change... you took advantage of the fact that all the values are `"name"`, but what if we wanted a different key? Or more than just one value? For example for the class you'd want `"title"` instead of `"name"` and an extra `"description"` attribute.

Comment: @dabadaba How did you handle those things in your question? You didn't. [Also this is starting to seem very much like example code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3652/42401). But to answer your question, you'd add a variable to `get_default` to change the `name`. And to add a description, you can return both the dict and the list, or do it later.

Comment: Right. I guess I'll post a new, more accurate question.